# AWS VPN NAT'ing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vpn, nat

This seems like a basic questions, but I'm having difficulty finding an appropriate solution.

I have a VPN connection to AWS and need to access my EC2 instance at, say, 10.1.0.40, but I already have a subnet locally for 10.1.0.x/24. How can I NAT the address in AWS so that when it receives data through this VPN, it maps, say 10.1.50.40 to 10.1.0.40?

This seems like it would be a pretty basic request, but I can't seem to find the solution on AWS. NAT instances and NAT gateways all talk about accessing the Internet from a private server and seem to have little to do with this simple address translation from a VPN connection.

What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using AWS's VPN service (via Virtual Private Gateway), or are you running your own software VPN (e.g. strongSwan) in AWS?

Comment: AWS's VPN service (via a VPG)

Comment: AWS VPN supports NAT traversal (NAT-T). If you are using NAT traversal (NAT-T) on your device, then you must include rules that allow UDP access over port 4500. (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/ec2-vpc-vpn-update-nat-traversal-additional-encryption-options-and-more/)

Comment: How can NAT-T help my scenario? If a user types 'ping 10.1.0.40' on the local network, the router won't know to try that address through the VPN. If they type 'ping 10.1.50.40' what defines the route to the proper address once the packets reach AWS? The link you sent implies that this is all on the local router side (not in AWS); do I still have to set up a NAT via the on premise router (is this exactly what NAT-T is)? Sorry for the questions on my part.

Comment: *"This seems like it would be a pretty basic request"*  Not really -- it's a scenario that should be avoided, by renumbering one of the networks.  The same subnet can't exist in two places on a routed network without **two** complementary sets of network address translations, back-to-back, such that devices on both sides always appear to be using a different IP from the perspective of devices on the other side of the NAT boundary.  It's messy, but could be implemented in your on-premise hardware VPN gateway device if it can do *all* of the necessary translation.

Comment: Thanks Michael. My "basic" comment was based on the fact that my 10 year old sonicwall router can do this, but I respect the fact that my office network is *way* less complicated than Amazon's datacenters. If I do not control the CIDR addresses in both locations (or cannot know one side a priori), then this functionality is often crucial. It just seems like something AWS would implement, basic or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use AWS NAT Gateway or an EC2 instance to solve the problem of CIDR overlap when setting up a VPN connection. For this to work either

- NATing should happen from On-Premise.
- Create a new private subnet to represent in your VPC side.
- To user Third-party VPN solution hosting on an EC2 instance which supports your use case, instead of using VPC native VPN.

For more details go through [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=223912) AWS Forum Discussion.

Comment: Thank you for your help.